# C# outlook interop saving meeting as appointment issues

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, icalendar, office-automation

I am trying to save an Outllok meeting ics file as an Outlook appointment ics but when i use do SaveAs to a folder location, it is saving as a meeting.

I have the following code but I can not seem to locate the issue. When I use .Display it shows as an appointment but .SaveAs is saving back as a meeting with recipients.

Any help is much appreciated

```
Outlook.Application App = new Outlook.Application();
string FPath = @"C:\\Documents\TestMeeting.ics"
var item = App.Session.OpenSharedItem(FPath) as Outlook.MeetingItem;
var AppointmentItem = item.GetAsssociatedAppointment(false);

AppointmentItem.MeetingStatus = Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olNonMeeting;
AppointmentItem.Display(true);
AppointmentItem.SaveAs(@"C:\\Documents\TestAppointment1.ics",Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olIcal);
```

Comment: Have you tried to create a new item from scratch in Outlook and then save it? Do you get the same results?

Comment: I have tried that and that saves correctly, however the meeting body content is a table with images and formatted and I can't get it to copy over correctly when creating a new appointment. I have tried item.Body, item.BodyFormat and item.RTFBody but it keeps copying across as rich text

Comment: Yes, appointments use RTF for message bodies. Use the RTFBody to set up any formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Save` method to save the just opened meeting into your calendar:

```
string FPath = @"C:\\Documents\TestMeeting.ics"
var item = App.Session.OpenSharedItem(FPath) as Outlook.MeetingItem;
item.Save();
// only after that you can try reprieving the associated appointment
var AppointmentItem = item.GetAsssociatedAppointment(false);
```

Also I'd recommend creating a new appointment item from scratch and then saving it to the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Eugene. I managed to get this working by creating a new appointment and using .BodyFormat and .RTFBody of the associated appointment. I have included the full code below for anyone in the future and marked your answer as correct. Apologies but at present I don't have enough rep to upvote otherwise I would. Many thanks

```
Outlook.Application App = new Outlook.Application();
string FPath = @"C:\\Documents\TestMeeting.ics"
var item = App.Session.OpenSharedItem(FPath) as Outlook.MeetingItem;
var AppointmentItem = item.GetAsssociatedAppointment(false);
Outlook.AppointmentItem ap1 = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)App.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
ap1.Start = AppointmentItem.Start;
ap1.Subject = AppointmentItem.Subject;
ap1.BodyFormat = AppointmentItem.BodyFormat;
ap1.RTFBody = AppointmentItem.RTFBody;
ap1.Location = AppointmentItem.Location;
ap1.SaveAs(@"C:\\Documents\TestAppointment1.ics",Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olIcal);
```